# Foreach loop and average in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I'm rather new to programming in general. I'm starting off with some exercises but I'm kind of getting stuck. I created an array and looped thru with a foreach loop to print out each individual number stored in the array, but I dont know what to do to find the average of the numbers and print it out.

```
<?php

$myArray = array(87,75,93,95);

foreach($myArray as $value){
    echo "$value <br>";
}

?>
```

Comment: easier: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could:

```
$avg = array_sum($myArray) / count($myArray);
echo $avg;
```

Where:

- `array_sum` calculates the sum of all elements in the given array.
- `count` outputs the total number of elements in the given array.

Answer (score 7):

only as an exercise, becuse if you actully wanted to do this you would use @kittykittybangbang's answer

```
<?php

$myArray = array(87,75,93,95);
$sum='';//create our variable 
foreach($myArray as $value){
    $sum+=$value; //adds $value to $sum
    //echo "$value <br>";
}
echo $sum;
?>
```

for the count `count($myArray);` makes the most senses but you could do that in the loop as well:

```
<?php

$myArray = array(87,75,93,95);
$sum= $count=0;// initiate interger variables
foreach($myArray as $value){
    $sum+=$value; //adds $value to $sum
   $count++; //add 1 on every loop 
   }
echo $sum;
echo $count;

//the basic math for any average:

echo $sum/$count; 
?>
```

if you don't create `$sum` and `$count` before the loop you would get notices returned from php, as the first time it tried to add to either, there would be noting to add to

Comment: Can i ask why $count=0, and $sum=''? :) $sum=0; makes more sense in this case (even if this works, of course)

Comment: Only as an exercise to help new programmer fella, we don't initiate variables meant to hold integers as strings :)