# Average of even numbers in array with for/while loop PHP

Tags: php

I need to get the average of all the even numbers in this array:

```
$aReeks = array(23,245,1,2,12,-10,46,6,66,9999,-55,348,56,6,66,983);
```

Can someone please help me? I'm already trying over an hour.

 I have to do it with a for/while loop.

Comment: sum up the array then divide by the number in the array; it's simple math. Don't they teach math in school now? http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32302645/foreach-loop-and-average-in-php

Comment: Show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Must be the same class and due today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37212309/getting-total-value-of-an-array-with-condition/37212711#37212711

Comment: Filter out the odd values, and then use sum and divide by the count: `$evens = array_filter($aReeks, function ($value) { return $value % 2 == 0; }); $evenAverage = arry_sum($evens) / count($evens);`

Comment: @AbraCadaver Huh... well will you look at that! or the same "guy".

Comment: And let's not forget http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37210893/getting-highest-even-number-out-of-an-array

Comment: @MarkBaker and no accepted answer nor in any of that guy's questions. I think this is a group troll or he's exchanging points between profiles.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting highest even number out of an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37210893/getting-highest-even-number-out-of-an-array)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting total value of an array with condition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37212309/getting-total-value-of-an-array-with-condition)

Comment: @Fred-ii- I still like my answer to that one using the proposed 7.1 piped syntax.... hope one of them submits that as their homework

Comment: possible profile duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/users/6171058/jari-rengeling - http://stackoverflow.com/users/6171680/kip-verslaafde

Comment: @MarkBaker *Aye,* for sure Mark. You know your stuff ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Use [array_sum()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) and [count()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php)

```
$aReeks = array(23,245,1,2,12,-10,46,6,66,9999,-55,348,56,6,66,983); 

 echo array_sum($Reeks) /count($aReeks);
```

you can get the array with only the even number this way

```
 foreach($aReeks as $key => $value) if($key&1) unset($aReeks[$key]);
```

and then

```
  echo array_sum($Reeks) /count($aReeks);
```

Comment: He asked for the average of the even numbers, not just the average.

Comment: by even index or even value?

Comment: By value... "I need to get the average of all the even numbers in this array:"

Comment: I have update the answer

Answer (score -1):

```
$count = 0;
$average = 0;
foreach ($aReeks as $value)
{
  $count++;
  $average += $value;
}
$average = $average/$count;

echo "average: {$average}<br>";
```