# PHP integer splits and addition

Tags: php, string, split

I am new in PHP. Trying to solve PHP integer splits and addition but little confuse how can i do it.
suppose given number is

```
41153
```

It has five digits i.e.

```
4,1,1,5,3
```

Average value of its digits is

```
(4+1+1+5+3)/5 = 2.8
```

As the average value 2.8 is less than 7, so we can say that 41153 is not a heavy number.

For split i use following function.

```
$num = str_split($firstval);
```

Comment: Well you probably want to add up the array values (*array_sum()*) and divide it by the amount (*count()*) of array elements.

Comment: Like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32302673/2734189

Comment: I didn't get my answer anywhere. The above given solution is not according to me. I want to take input from user and the user can type anything like "411567" now i want to convert this into 4+1+1+5+6+7. Please help me i am stuck.

Comment: `$average = array_sum(str_split($firstval))/strlen($firstval);`